# Limit a variable value to certain predefined values

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

What's the shortest and simplest way to do this?

For example:

```
$var = $_GET['something'];
// how to limit the value of $var to "10", "20", "30", "40", 
// and "" for any other input ?
```

I mean is there a php helper function that can do this, without having to use 5 IFs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) is suitable in this case:

```
if(!in_array($var, array("10", "20", "30", "40"))
{
    // $var will be "" if it does not equal: "10", "20", "30", or "40"
    $var = "";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I used: `$var = in_array($_GET["something"], array(10, 20, 30, 40)) ? $_GET["something"] : '';` It's even shorter :D

Comment: Yes. This is the best choice. You should check it the correct answer. Well done Tim!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build a predefined array and then validate against it:

```
$array = (10, 20, 30, 40);
if(in_array($array, $var)){
   // validated
} else {
  // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

limit or check?

```
if (isset($_GET['something'])) { 
  $validSomethings = array("10", "20", "30", "40");
  foreach ($validSomethings as $something) { 
       if ($something == $_GET['something']) { 
            // it's valid.  do it.
       } else {
            // not valid
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

And a more unconventional method:

```
$map = array(10, 20, 30, 40);   // == range(10, 40, 10);
$map = array_combine($map, $map);

$value = "{$map[$_GET['something']]}";
```

Which has the advantage of implicitly generating a notice on unwanted parameters (for logging).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking.  There are many alternatives to 5 ifs.
You can use math to limit the responses.

```
$var = (is_numeric($var))?(($var>40 || $var < 10)?"":floor($var/10)*10):"";
```

You can use a single [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
switch($var){
  case "10":
  case "20":
  case "30":
  case "40":
    //do something?
  break;
  default:
    $var = "";
    //do something else?
  break;
}
```